# swift3 how to show navigation viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift3, widget, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I would like to open the specific view from the notification widget.
normally other answers are create new view..`(let viewcontroller = ... )`
so If you continue to call, continue use memory..

So, I want to open viewA, which is already opened in my app, and then move to viewB.

My application structure is basically a viewA when the application is launched.

What I think is that instead of creating a new viewA, I want to move to viewB using the  navigation.push from the already existing viewA.

The way to check whether a particular page already exists, how to show that page at the top , and how to navigation.push is work.

now i'm using this code to open viewA from `Appdelegate`

```
let MainView: Main_View_List_ = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main_List_View") as! Main_View_List_
let nav = UINavigationontroller.init(rootViewController: MainView)
UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the navigation controller, you'll want to do something like this to pop back to viewA:

```
     for viewController in nav.viewControllers {
         if viewController is ViewAClass {
           viewController.pushViewBFlag = true
           nav.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
          return
     }
  }
```

Once you get back to viewA, you can check for pushViewBFlag and create and push viewB.

Alternately, since it seems that you are setting viewA as the root of your navigation controller, you could do: `nav.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` to get back to viewA. You would need to then handle pushing viewB from viewA.